# Send an order to a Fax machine automatically?

Tags: orders

I have a question regarding a placed order: Can a placed order automatically be sent to a Fax machine besides an E-Mail address?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is anyone still using a Fax machine?

Comment: I need this for a Pizza delivery shop. They must receive the order by Fax machine.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this would be to use an E-Mail to FAX Gateway Service. For example hellofax or an alternative.